# Statically created Html table link field value click redirect and display those corresponding values in another page in java

Tags: java, jsp

I have statically created Html table but i need to send query string and  get id value is dynamically and table have link field click link field send and display those details to another page can anyone tell me how to do this
 my table:

```
   <table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr data-url="Timer.jsp">
            <td>39401602</td>
            <td>6/21/2013</td>
            <td>Open</td>
            <td>$79.99</td>
            <td><a href="Timer.jsp">Amazing Widget (16 GB, White)</a></td>
            <td>JohnathanDoe</td>
 </tr>
        <tr data-url="Timer.jsp">
            <td>39401602</td>
            <td>6/21/2013</td>
            <td>Open</td>
            <td>$79.99</td>
            <td><a href="#">Amazing Widget (16 GB, White)</a></td>
            <td>JohnathanDoe</td> </tr>
    </tbody>
</table> </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('table.table tr').click(function () {
        window.location.href = $(this).data('Timer.jsp');
    });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send send query string in `<a>` tag

```
<table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>39401602</td>
                <td>6/21/2013</td>
                <td>Open</td>
                <td>$79.99</td>
                <td><a href="Timer.jsp?id=39401602">Amazing Widget (16 GB, White)</a></td>
                <td>JohnathanDoe</td>
     </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>39401602</td>
                <td>6/21/2013</td>
                <td>Open</td>
                <td>$79.99</td>
                <td><a href="Timer.jsp?id=39401602">Amazing Widget (16 GB, White)</a></td>
                <td>JohnathanDoe</td> </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: HI,@Neha Shettar, but i need to pass query string id value is dynamically how to pass dynamically

Comment: ur table is not dynamically generated?